# Why does some electrets buzz and others have fantastic SNR on the same pre-amp?

Tags: amplifier, audio, microphone, electret

I have a tiny wireless mic preamp which sounds muffled. I swapped it for high quality capsules, they produce crazy amounts of buzzing. I am using short wires and complete foil shielding. The tiny low quality muffled sounding capsule has excellent SNR with no buzzing problems.

Why do different capsules produce crazy volumes of buzzing and others have good SNR for the same pre-amp?

Comment: Which modules?  Exactly how is it being driven?  Some elects contain FET pre-amplifiers, some do not.

Comment: Some mics are balanced, and some are not. Buzzing might come from poor or no balance.

Comment: A preamp can produce buzzing if it has a poor rejection of power supply hum. Try powering with a battery and if the buzzing goes away then it is the power supply rejection causing the buzzing. sometimes a "ground loop" causes buzzing.